# How to recover deposit to incorrect address

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

i need some guidance. I deposited Bitcoin from LUNO to an address in Gatehub. The Bitcoin has not arrived in my Gatehub wallet. I believe it went to an incorrect address. How do i trace it and recover it.

Comment: Transactions in bitcoin can take up to an hour, with the ever increasing activity on the network it will take longer incrementallly. But if you send it to the wrong wallet, it is lost and permanently unretreiveable. You are your own bank and that comes with a high price if done incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

Log into Luno and click on transactions.

[image]

This should list the deposit that you did to gatehub. In my example in the screenshot this is a transfer I did to the waves platform 
[image]
If you click on that transaction in the list it will show the transaction number of this deposit. The transaction number will be hyperlinked so you can click on it and it will launch a new page that allows you to view the transaction in the blockchain explorer. Check your transaction in the blockchain explorer and see how many times it has been confirmed and whether it has been added to a block.